# При скачивании сайта через wget, как пропускать определённый каталог?

Tags: linux, wget

Пользуюсь под Linux программой для скачивание wget , в одном из скачиваемых ресурсов есть директория screencast которая весит очень много , мой Линукс установлен на флеш накопитель объёмом 32ггб и такую раскошь не могу позволить ,как запретить скачивание всех файлов и директорий **кроме директории screencast** , закачку сайта выполнил по этой команде :

**wget -r -k -l 7 -p -E -nc https://site.ru**

Comment: А кто вас научил пробелы перед знаками препинания ставить?

Comment: @0andriy чего ?

Comment: Вы понимаете русский язык? Вы пишите неправильно, а именно знаки препинания не отделяются пробелом от предшествующего слова.

Comment: @0andriy в школу идите преподавайте , я не задавал вопрос о грамоте русского

Comment: Вот уж поистине... Будьте здоровы!

Comment: @0andriy ещё один минус можешь поставить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--exclude-directories=screencast 

-X list | -exclude-directories=list
```

Определить разделённый запятыми список каталогов, которые вы не желаете копировать на свою машину. Элементы списка list могут содержать метасимволы.

Например

```
wget --exclude-directories=misc -r -k -l 7 -p -E -nc https://eternallybored.org/
```

Comment: а что с этим делать ? как правильно это вживить в  wget -r -k -l 7 -p -E -nc https://site.ru ?

Comment: wget --exclude-directories=screencast  -r -k -l 7 -p -E -nc site.ru Но должен быть точно указан адрес screencast

Comment: @codename0082016, ему как раз надо всё исключить **кроме** screencast*.